# Simulating dynamic table cell width growth using divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When it comes to splitting page width into several columns I have always used a table. with fixed table width that cells widths are dynamically determined.

[image]

but now I want to do this using divs instead of table cells.. It's very easy using javascript/jquery:

```
var desiredWidth = 500;
var totalWidth = $('#div1').outerWidth() + $('#div2').outerWidth() + $('#div3').outerWidth();
var scale = desiredWidth / totalWidth;
$('#div1').outerWidth(scale * $('#div1').outerWidth());
$('#div2').outerWidth(scale * $('#div2').outerWidth());
$('#div3').outerWidth(scale * $('#div3').outerWidth());
```

But the problem is that I always load css in header and javascripts right before closing body tag to avoid render blocking and this way page loads mal-formed till the all scripts are loaded.

Is there any way to do this with css, without using javascript?

Comment: You may be forced to set a `max-width` on your table cells that would typically have the smaller widths. Then, don't specify a width for your 'largest' table cell and it should occupy the remaining space and wrap when required.

Comment: @lindsay, I think you have misunderstood the question. I want to use divs instead of table cells but I want these divs to have the same functionality.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's a quick [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQt69/). Is this what you had in mind? Admittedly it's using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

Comment: yes exactly but the reason I didn't want to do this way is as stated in w3schools.com: Note: The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", and "table-row-group" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Comment: but however althought I had thought about this idea but hadn't tested it. thanks for your fiddle. it works great. I think i should get over IE7 ;) and use exactly as you did.

Comment: You could try the use of `display: inline;` on your columns in and `float: left;` on the parent in IE7. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQt69/1/).

Comment: @lindsay please add it as answer so that you can get credit for it. and many thanks for you fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples here.

IE8 and higher [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQt69/).

```
.container {
   display: table;
}
.col {
   display: table-cell;
}
```

IE7 [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQt69/1/).

```
.container {
   float: left;
}
.col {
   display: inline;
}
```